# How to get URL of webview in every five seconds?

Tags: android, webview

Whenever i try to get url of webview and try to  display it in logs my app crashes.
This is my code...
Everything is working but it crashes everytime after finishing the page.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String user;
String password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent i = getIntent();
   user = i.getStringExtra("username");
   password = i.getStringExtra("password");



    final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    final WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl("javascript: (function() {document.getElementById('ft_un').value= '" + user + "';}) ();");
            view.loadUrl("javascript: (function() {document.getElementById('ft_pd').value= '" + password + "';}) ();");
            view.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){ document.querySelectorAll(\"input[type='submit']\")[0].click();})();");


            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            String currentUrl = webView.getUrl();
            Log.i("url", currentUrl);


        }
    }, 5000);




}
```

}

And this is the Error i am getting

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
                                                                     Process: com.anshuman.cgcautologin, PID: 8609
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'Timer-0'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 1) {256ea4a6} called on null, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 1) {256ea4a6})
                                                                         at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:2204)
                                                                         at android.webkit.WebView.getUrl(WebView.java:1293)
                                                                         at com.anshuman.cgcautologin.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:62)
                                                                         at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'Timer-0'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 1) {256ea4a6} called on null, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 1) {256ea4a6})
                                                                         at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:2194)
                                                                         at android.webkit.WebView.getUrl(WebView.java:1293) 
                                                                         at com.anshuman.cgcautologin.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:62) 
                                                                         at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Answer (score 1):

`WebView.getUrl()` needs to run on the UI thread.

```
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    String currentUrl = webView.getUrl();
                    Log.i("url", currentUrl);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 5000);
```

or even better:

```
webView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        String currentUrl = webView.getUrl();
        Log.i("url", currentUrl);
    }
}, 5000);
```

Okay, that won't repeat.  But really, do you need to log every five seconds?  Override `onPageStarted()` in `WebViewClient`, you already have `onPageFinished()`, just log the start time and end time of the page load.

Comment: Actually what i want is when my app open it will go to college website and it will programatically fill all details like username , password and then it will automatically click on login button. This part is working fine after that what i want is that page which i got after login button press will reload in every seconds. Please how should i do this

Comment: I would put the `webView.postDelayed()` inside the `onPageFinished()`.  So that way if the page takes longer than five seconds to load, it will still work okay.

Comment: no it doesn't matter for me how much time it take to load. The problem is my college has some security that in every 1200 second you have to login in again but if i reload my page before that then it will give again 1200 second. So what i want to do is after login in my app will automatically reload the page in every  1100 second and user dont need to login in their account every time